# Does the user specific PATH in Windows roam across machines?

Tags: windows, path, roaming

In Windows there are two environment variables which make up the PATH, a user specific PATH and the system wide PATH.

Does anyone know if the user PATH roams across machines, or is it specific to a user *and* a machine?

Answer (score 0):

It is specific for a user *AND* machine. It does not roam.

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented anywhere? Or are you just speaking from experience?

Comment: This is from experience. I haven't found an article about it

Comment: But anyways, it's easy enough to test :D